# Migrating from Tiles 2.1.4 to 2.2.2 - Property-based Configuration Removed

Tags: spring, apache, tiles, apache-tiles, tiles2

We have a project that is using `Tiles 2.1.4 & Spring 3.2.8` and I am trying to upgrade it to `Tiles 2.2.2 & Spring 4.3.1`. The code used for configuring Tiles is like this:

```
import org.apache.tiles.TilesException;
import org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO;
import org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.BasicRendererFactory;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer;

import java.util.Properties;

public class DefaultTilesConfigurer extends TilesConfigurer {
    ....

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws TilesException {
        //set default properties
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty(BasicRendererFactory.TYPE_RENDERERS_INIT_PARAM, "template,"+SkinTemplateAttributeRenderer.class.getName());
        props.setProperty(BasicRendererFactory.DEFAULT_RENDERER_INIT_PARAM, UntypedSkinAttributeRenderer.class.getName());
        props.setProperty(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.CHECK_REFRESH_INIT_PARAMETER, Boolean.toString(refreshable));
        super.setTilesProperties(props);
        //initialize
        super.afterPropertiesSet();
    }
}
```

The thing is `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer#setTilesProperties` is removed in `Tiles 2.2`. I have checked [2.1](https://tiles.apache.org/2.1/framework/tutorial/configuration.html) and [2.2](https://tiles.apache.org/2.2/framework/tutorial/configuration.html) configuration pages of Apache but I didn't understand how I can configure Tiles 2.2 with same parameters.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to strongly consider whether it makes sense to use Tiles 2.2 with Spring 4, [given that it's officially deprecated in favor of Tiles 3.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Migrating-from-earlier-versions-of-the-Spring-Framework#third-party-dependencies-1).  Why not upgrade to Tiles 3 while you're at it?

That being said, `TilesConfigurer#setTilesProperties()` in Spring 3 is equivalent to setting `init-param` elements on the `TilesServlet` context, so you could move the configuration to your `web.xml` file, e.g.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>tiles</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.tiles.web.startup.TilesServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>
          org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.BasicRendererFactory.DEFAULT_RENDERER_INIT_PARAM
        </param-name>
        <param-value>
          com.test.UntypedSkinAttributeRenderer
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    ...
</servlet>
```

Note: the above is deprecated in Tiles 2.2.

> WARNING!!! Configuration with initialization parameters is deprecated!
>   If you still want to use it, please refer to 2.1 version of this page.

References:

https://tiles.apache.org/2.1/framework/tutorial/configuration.html

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/tiles2/TilesConfigurer.html

Comment: Hi @ck1, I definitely agree with you about upgrading to Tiles 3 but it means re-writing lots of code in our application. Thanks for reply.